# how can I set animation for expandable list of it's child in android?

Tags: android, animation

I want set animation for my expandable list when list up and down the list show a good appearance and don't up &down very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the dependency in your build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.aakira:expandable-layout:1.6.0@aar'
}
```

create xml file

```
<com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/expandableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:ael_expanded="false"
    app:ael_duration="500"
    app:ael_interpolator="bounce"
    app:ael_orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sample" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
        android:text="sample2" />
</com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>
```

add java code

```
ExpandableLinearLayout expandableLayout
 = (ExpandableLinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.expandableLayout);

child.setText("Sets text from a server");
expandableLayout.initLayout(); // Recalculate size of children

// recycler view
// you must set a ViewHolder#setIsRecyclable(false) and ExpandableLinearLayout#setInRecyclerView(true) 

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
    holder.expandableLinearLayout.setInRecyclerView(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this method for your child view.

```
private void animateView(final View target, final int type) {
        Animation anim = new ExpandCollapseAnimation(target,type);
        anim.setDuration(getAnimationDuration());
        anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            if (type == ExpandCollapseAnimation.EXPAND) {
                if (parent instanceof ListView) {
                    ListView listView = (ListView) parent;
                    int movement = target.getBottom();

                    Rect r = new Rect();
                    boolean visible = target.getGlobalVisibleRect(r);
                    Rect r2 = new Rect();
                    listView.getGlobalVisibleRect(r2);

                    if (!visible) {
                        listView.smoothScrollBy(movement, getAnimationDuration());
                    } else {
                        if (r2.bottom == r.bottom) {
                            listView.smoothScrollBy(movement,getAnimationDuration());
                        }
                      }
                }
            }
        }
    });
    target.startAnimation(anim);
}
```